# HELP! mistakenly removed pop os from bios boot menu

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub, bios, pop-os

My laptop is Thinkpad E590, UEFI Bios version is: ROYET51W (1.34). Machine type model : 20NBS0B800
I dual boot Pop os and win10 on my lenevo thinkpad. Both of them are install on my ssd.
I always used the bios boot order to boot from pop to windows to pop.

[image: as you can see here]

Last night while switching to pop from windows, I mistakenly pressed the key to reset defaults in the bios menu and now the Pop OS entry is gone from the bios boot order, only windows boot loader is there and my laptop only boots to windows.
I tried booting into pop os live usb and use boot repair tool to fix it but is gives a message “NVRAM locked”

Here is the complete output:

```
boot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20230817_0841]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================





modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.6-76060206-generic
ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi/vars': No such file or directory

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p3,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p2/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


/boot/efi added in nvme0n1p3/fstab
rm /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
rm /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount nvme0n1p2 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi
ls: cannot access '/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/efi': No such file or directory
No nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/efi/ ubuntu/mint folder

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of nvme0n1p3 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.6-76060206-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 efibootmgr -v before grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.


chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 uname -r
6.2.6-76060206-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/efi/pop/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p2
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/efi/pop/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p5
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi/efi/pop/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 efibootmgr -v after grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

Error: NVram is locked (Pop not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.4.6-76060406-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.4.6-76060406-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.6-76060206-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.6-76060206-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-76060200-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-76060200-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.11-76060111-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.11-76060111-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.0.12-76060006-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.0.12-76060006-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.0.6-76060006-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.0.6-76060006-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.0.3-76060003-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.0.3-76060003-generic
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p3/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.
Error: NVram is locked (Pop not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Locked-NVram detected.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    585032 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location 
    and looks for (,gpt1)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/pop/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/pop/grubx64.efi /efi/pop/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/pop/grubx64.efi /efi/pop/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (22.04) on nvme0n1p3
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p6

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X] from Intel Corporation Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Pop 64-bit (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: R0YET51W (1.34 )(1.34) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 001D
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 001D,0010,0011,0012,0013,0014,001A,0019,0018,0000,001B,001C,001E
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,7742b7be-bc71-42d0-846f-ca6fa543c1c3,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Regulatory Information    FvFile(478c92a0-2622-42b7-a65d-5894169e4d24)
Boot0015  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0016  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0017  MEBx Hot Key  FvFile(ac6fd56a-3d41-4efd-a1b9-870293811a28)
Boot0018* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0019* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot001A* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001B* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001C* ATA HDD1  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f601)
Boot001D* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001E* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot001F* IDER BOOT CDROM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,1)
Boot0020* IDER BOOT Floppy  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,0)
Boot0021* ATA HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)
Boot0022* ATAPI CD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
c152ec201c37b6e97bbc2207e49d1271   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p1/pop/grubx64.efi
553e913655a8cc0640c35c100e83fa9d   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
19cb825a89130540289671cfa7fcb7c9   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
467b94109a1cee7b81b6f247e0406757   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p2/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p2/BOOT/bootx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p2/pop/grubx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p5/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p5/BOOT/bootx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p5/pop/grubx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p2   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p6   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p7   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p2   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda6    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 8E323518-DF73-456C-83F9-3F5698822E39
           Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
sda1        2048    9412607   9410560  4.5G Linux filesystem
sda2   841996288 1057988607 215992320  103G Linux filesystem
sda3     9412608  533700607 524288000  250G Linux filesystem
sda4   533700608  533733375     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
sda5   533733376  841996287 308262912  147G Linux filesystem
sda6  1057988608 1953523711 895535104  427G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: 496677B5-D793-41B8-8699-E313AE5898F1
              Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
nvme0n1p2   1050624   3147771   2097148  1024M EFI System
nvme0n1p3   3147776 275034109 271886334 129.6G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p4 275034112 275066879     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p5 275066880 275271679    204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p6 275271680 499071628 223799949 106.7G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p7 499073024 500115455   1042432   509M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdb: 14.84 GiB, 15938355200 bytes, 31129600 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x31d1b347
      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *          0  5167231  5167232  2.5G  0 Empty
sdb2           488     8679     8192    4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb3       5169152 31129599 25960448 12.4G 83 Linux
Disk zram0: 15.46 GiB, 16595812352 bytes, 4051712 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1:;
1:1049kB:4819MB:4818MB:ext4::;
3:4819MB:273GB:268GB:ext4:IUB:;
4:273GB:273GB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
5:273GB:431GB:158GB:ext4::;
2:431GB:542GB:111GB:ext4:Files:;
6:542GB:1000GB:459GB:ext4:Files:;
sdb:15.9GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Innostor Innostor:;
2:250kB:4444kB:4194kB:::esp;
3:2647MB:15.9GB:13.3GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:256GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:TS256GMTE220S:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:1612MB:1074MB:fat32::boot, esp;
3:1612MB:141GB:139GB:ext4::;
4:141GB:141GB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
5:141GB:141GB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
6:141GB:256GB:115GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
7:256GB:256GB:534MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sdb: 4.24MiB:2524MiB:2520MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                     
├─sda1      ext4     46ad3451-2c3c-4e9d-8014-21deeed7193a bba51c29-fb73-4c6c-a78a-37baefc3ff78                          
├─sda2      ext4     542ba930-10bf-4109-97ec-6d6c571293aa a428af4d-5c65-4fbe-a946-7dbab87d4155                          Files
├─sda3      ext4     cb5d4807-bd15-4ed9-a6bf-b603fe0b1417 9eb83de3-c4fb-4bcb-903c-903de91444cc                          IUB
├─sda4                                                    aaffd2f1-76fb-4325-9f99-88f891cd67b7                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda5      ext4     9378c2ec-2804-48f8-8f54-6921e85e7133 6cae5025-57d9-492d-8452-7d852548f501                          
└─sda6      ext4     9c91d588-c49a-49cd-80b2-4ff5d1e7ac6b b31d0ce1-e3a9-49e7-a595-aa235b4c1c1c                          Files
sdb         iso9660  2023-07-27-16-47-03-00                                                    Pop_OS 22.04 amd64 Intel 
├─sdb1      iso9660  2023-07-27-16-47-03-00               31d1b347-01                          Pop_OS 22.04 amd64 Intel 
├─sdb2      vfat     F821-BFD2                            31d1b347-02                                                   
└─sdb3      ext4     6ec36e95-f87e-43c2-a14f-f9054abdde41 31d1b347-03                          writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     FCDA-59BF                            7742b7be-bc71-42d0-846f-ca6fa543c1c3                          EFI System Partition
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat     EACC-8468                            0606ca37-dbb2-4cb3-80c4-bb2357108de5                          
├─nvme0n1p3 ext4     966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6 6fd0782f-5ea9-4142-acf6-f1c0695383b2                          
├─nvme0n1p4                                               db0c7910-056f-4786-b989-c9c34a8343b5                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p5 vfat     743D-5666                            8af1ffe8-0a9c-4578-a45c-a7ea3981f83f                          EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     3A744CBC744C7D1F                     6e57336d-baa0-4bdf-b829-ef2baf5e8f73                          Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p7 ntfs     8448A13448A125C0                     65659d6e-ae67-43ad-9c71-bcd255066f06                          

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-08-17.0/crash]   11.4G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-08-17.0/log]     11.4G   0% /var/log
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                 471.6M   8% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                1014.5M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                  25.9G  74% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                  88.6M   8% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6                                                  13.1G  88% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/nvme0n1p7                                                  88.3M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7
/dev/sda1                                                        4.1G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2                                                       47.8G  48% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                                                      133.5G  40% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda5                                                      136.3G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda6                                                       33.2G  87% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sdb1                                                           0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 96db60c5-65e1-49fa-9e0e-598462aa6093 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

==================== nvme0n1p2/efi/pop/grub.cfg (filtered) =====================

search.fs_uuid 966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Pop GNU/Linux   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.4.6-76060406-generic   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.2.6-76060206-generic   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.2.0-76060200-generic   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.1.11-76060111-generic   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.0.12-76060006-generic   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.0.6-76060006-generic   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.0.3-76060003-generic   966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-FCDA-59BF
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p3/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

UUID=EACC-8468  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p3: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  27.102535248 = 29.101125632   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  21.832614899 = 23.442591744   boot/vmlinuz-6.0.12-76060006-generic           2
  16.832557678 = 18.073821184   boot/vmlinuz-6.0.3-76060003-generic            1
 107.375972748 = 115.294072832  boot/vmlinuz-6.0.6-76060006-generic            2
 107.863937378 = 115.818020864  boot/vmlinuz-6.1.11-76060111-generic           2
  96.029495239 = 103.110885376  boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-76060200-generic            2
  27.102535248 = 29.101125632   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.6-76060206-generic            2
  73.474967957 = 78.893146112   boot/vmlinuz-6.4.6-76060406-generic            1
  27.102535248 = 29.101125632   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 114.997066498 = 123.477159936  boot/initrd.img                               41
 123.906944275 = 133.044068352  boot/initrd.img-6.0.12-76060006-generic       35
 121.641445160 = 130.611507200  boot/initrd.img-6.0.3-76060003-generic         7
 123.335052490 = 132.430004224  boot/initrd.img-6.0.6-76060006-generic        16
 127.344722748 = 136.735354880  boot/initrd.img-6.1.11-76060111-generic       44
 128.348628998 = 137.813291008  boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-76060200-generic        49
 114.997066498 = 123.477159936  boot/initrd.img-6.2.6-76060206-generic        41
 121.597763062 = 130.564603904  boot/initrd.img-6.4.6-76060406-generic         6
 114.997066498 = 123.477159936  boot/initrd.img.old                           41

=================== nvme0n1p3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 May  2 18:31 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom

==================== nvme0n1p5/efi/pop/grub.cfg (filtered) =====================

search.fs_uuid 966163a2-de36-4f5a-a1c7-2a5b12b324c6 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
sprunge.us ko ()
```

Can someone PLEASE help me repair this? I have so many important files on my pop os I really need to get it fixed.

Comment: Please update your *exact* computer model string and BIOS version. Some Thinkpads had *severe* problems (got bricked!) when resetting NVRAM. Fortunately this didn't happen to you, but it indicates that errors in the BIOS have a plausible probability in this case.

Comment: @dodrg ohmygod. My laptop is Thinkpad E590, UEFI Bios version is: ROYET51W (1.34). Machine type model : 20NBS0B800. What should I do? I dont wanna brick it; I dont wanna lose my current os data as well.

Comment: your BIOS is up to date. As no bug corrections have been made (only security updates), I think the problems that bricked some thinkpad should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Pop!_OS uses GRUB 2 as bootloader;
it has a bunch of tools that help us but today one of them failed;

as you can see the issue is the lack of **efivar fs**;

**efivarfs** module is mandatory but it would be automatically loaded if Linux booted in UEFI mode;

so, *the easiest way to get it*, is to boot a live in that mode;
here is a [way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios) to check it;
once, you right booted, the *boot-repair* should goes fine!

References:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I’m really sorry I’m a bit confused. I am already in UEFI mode. I checked it using [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode" and it says UEFI. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You also show 3 ESP's on your NVMe drive. You should only have one, but its GUID/partUUID will have to match UEFI boot entry and the 3 line grub.cfg must have the UUID of where your full grub.cfg is in your install. And that one must the the one in your fstab so its updated with changes. Why 3 ESPs? That can confuse some UEFI systems, but probably not related to locked UEFI. Check UEFI settings for another setting on locking UEFI changes for security. You may have to review manual to see details as brief descriptions in UEFI often do not tell everything.

Comment: @RedMist from your posted output: `ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi/vars': No such file or directory`, something is wrong...